# ASP.NET OmniSharp server is not running on Ubuntu Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, mono, visual-studio-code, dnvm

After [setting up VS Code](http://xameeramir.github.io/install-vs-code-ubuntu-linux/), I'm trying to run an [ASP.NET 5](http://asp.net/vnext) project using [Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)'s [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics) on [Ubuntu Linux 14.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

The [DNVM installed is for Mono](http://xameeramir.github.io/configure-net-ubuntu-linux/). Following the steps given on [VS code's official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5), the project is created with [Yeoman scaffolder](http://yeoman.io/).

Whenever trying to start the project, I get the following error:

> OmniSharp server is not running.

I found some posts when trying to solve this but most seems to be addressing either [Console project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx) or are given for [OS x](http://www.apple.com/in/osx/):

- [For a Console App](http://michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/#comment-2483329387)
- [This is for debugging not running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861576/2404470)
- The output of `mono --version` shows that it is [>3.12](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_mono-debugging):

[image]

- [My dnvm is already the latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34845933/2404470)

[image: DNVM is already the latest]

I can run the project by using `dnx web` command from **Terminal**.

However, my simple question:

- How do I run ASP.NET 5 on Ubuntu using **[VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2659)**?

> Side question : Not sure by when the [debugging will be supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5#_debugging). Any rumours about [the extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_common-questions) will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `mono --version`?

Comment: @LexLi I have updated the question to add the output of `mono --version` Does it help understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/27) and not specifically with [VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2659)